# To find percentage for five subjects in a class

Tags: typescript

I am a fresher and I am new to TypeScript,

To find percentage I used this:

```typescript
pere() {
  this.E=(((+this.English+ +this.Tamil+ +this.Maths+ +this.Science+ +this.Social)/500)*100);
  console.log(this.E);
```

I added the values and got the answer but I need a clear understanding of what is happening in the function.

Comment: This should be get the average marks in the 5 subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in that function is unnecessarily complex. Instead of `((...)/500)*100`, it should just be `(...)/5`.

To get the average of X values, you add the values up and then divide the resulting sum by the count of values. For instance, to get the average of the values 2 6 3 4 1, you do `(2 + 6 + 3 + 4 + 1) / 5`:

```js
console.log((2 + 6 + 3 + 4 + 1) / 5); // 3.2
```

The code in the function you've shown is adding five values together, then dividing by 500 rather than 5 and then multiplying the result by 100. There's no point to that and in fact it can make the result less precise than it would otherwise have been, because JavaScript's numbers are IEEE-754 double-precision floating point, which are not perfectly precise. Dividing a number by 100 and then multiplying it by 100 again can be a lossy process.

Comment: Thank you sir, but need to find percentage for five and 7 subjects when the total marks for each subject is only 100 marks each,

Comment: @pravinprince - That isn't what you asked. You asked what the code did. That's what I explained.

Comment: please help me to write a program for getting percentage for 7 subjects, each subject is of 100 marks, and the students in a class are 27 and i have to calculate percentage for all the students who gets different marks in the exams,thank you

Comment: @pravinprince - I'm afraid I don't understand what you're looking for there. It *sounds* like just a simple average as above: Add up the marks and divide by 7.

Comment: Thank you for writing sir, i will be more specific with my problems sir, and i will elaborate it properly next time. Thank you again sir